# How to run my unit tests in github action workflow?

Tags: java, android, workflow, github-actions

So I developed a few tests for my Android app and I need to run the tests using github actions workflow. Here is my .yml file, but I don't know how to run the tests( and get their logs):

```
name: Java CI with Gradle

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches: Features

jobs:
  test:
    name: Run Unit Tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Unit tests
        run: bash ./gradlew test --stacktrace
      - name: Unit tests results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: unit-tests-results
          path: ./app
```

I'm not sure how to run all the app and then run all the tests, can someone give me a hint? I searched all the internet, I came across this code, but it doesn't work. My artifact is the whole app itself
The tests are: 
1.SignUpTest.java 
2.SignInTest.java 
3.AddToCart.java

Comment: What's wrong with the `Unit tests` step?

Comment: Not sure what it actually happens. The upload artifacts step uploads the whole app, but all i wanted was the logs from tests. Maybe that step is wrong

Comment: You will need to save the logs from the tests to a file, and then upload the file

Comment: If any tests fail, GitHub Actions will output the reason. Why do you need to get the logs? Where do you plan to upload them?